# Access the json I post to dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am new to dialogflow.
The system I am using is sending to dialogflow this json.

```
        {
    "insertId": "ptdlkdcqiw",
    "jsonPayload": {
        "session": "************",
        "queryInput": {
        "languageCode": "en",
        "text": {
            "text": "test"
        }
        },
        "queryParams": {
        "payload": {
            "support_board": {
            "conversation_id": "23",
            "user_id": "18"
            }
        }
        }
    },
    "resource": {
        "type": "global",
        "labels": {
        "project_id": "********"
        }
    },
    "timestamp": "2024-01-15T10:41:51.074664Z",
    "severity": "INFO",
    "labels": {
        "location_id": "us-central1",
        "session_id": "18",
        "environment_id": "",
        "agent_id": "159074f8-ecb4-4a10-ad69-44082231daa9"
    },
    "logName": "*********",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2024-01-15T10:41:51.454070516Z"
    }
```

How can I get the data "queryParams" to use it in a webhook.
Thanks.